# Calling an HTTP triggered Azure function from another one

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have a VisualStudio solution with 3 Azure Functions: Functions A, B and C. All them are HTTP triggered. Now, I need to create a new function D (a durable function?) to chain functions A, B and C. Depending on the parameters reveived in function D, it has to execute A-B-C, or maybe A-C, or maybe some other combination. But I still need to call A, B and C independently as they are called now that function D doesn't exist. So, what I need to know is:

1. Creating a durable function D is the best solution to do what I need to do?
2. If so, how do I call functions A, B and C from function D?

Thanks

Comment: How long does it take to complete calls to A, B and C? If the total amount is less than a few minutes you could just call them sequentially and in any order in D.

Comment: Sometimes A, B and C can take a "long" time to finish, let's say more than 10 minutes each

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have mentioned using the function chaining pattern with Durable Functions is definitely the way to go. This is a more resilient solution that calling the A/B/C functions directly.

I recommend to look at the [docs and code samples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=csharp). I have also some [YouTube videos](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLoSzmz8jSD1fahiSdKdf4073AOdti_rx8) about Durable Functions.

Function D will be your orchestrator function and this function will chain activity functions A, B and C together (including some if statements to either do ABC or AC).

In addition you need a client function (E) in order to kick off the orchestrator function. In your case a HTTP client function is probably most likely.

You mention you still want to call function A, B and C individually so without the orchestrator. I recommend you move the logic out of those functions so it will become reusable across different functions (also better unit testable).

So class `A'` has your logic. You can call `A'` from the new `ActivityA` function (as part of the function chaining) and call it from the regular `FunctionA` Http triggered function as you already have.

**Durable Function chaining:**

```
E (client) -> D (orchestrator) -> A (activity, uses A') 
                                  B (activity, uses B')
                                  C (activity, uses C')
```

**Regular HTTP trigger functions:**

```
FunctionA (uses A')
FunctionB (uses B')
FunctionC (uses C')
```

Comment: Yesterday I started to build something like what you describe, but I had some doubts. Your answer confirms that I'm on the right track. Thanks!

Comment: surely if you need to chain them like this what is point of seperating them in the first place. wouldnt this prevent scaling and engine using multiple instances

Answer (score 1):

Creating a durable function project is good for chaining work together in a variety of patterns. If you did this you would need to create and start function with some sort of trigger, and then use an orchestrator to call activities that do work.

If you just want to use an http trigger then you need to have an http client trigger the function with a request.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the previous answer. You can use durable functions for function chaining. If you want MS examples to understand how durable functions work, see here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/create-long-running-serverless-workflow-with-durable-functions/